# How can I parse freemarker template's following structure?

Tags: java, template-engine, freemarker

I have some problem with following:

```
someMethod(List recipients, String message) {

        SimpleHash model = new SimpleHash();
        model.put("message", message);

        for (String email : recipients) {
            model.put("name", email);
            String buildHTML = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils
                    .processTemplateIntoString(freemarkerConfiguration
                            .getTemplate("customMail.ftl", locale, "UTF-8"), model);
            model.remove("name");
            create(buildHTML, email);
        }
}
```

That's ok! but parameter "message"  has similar to the following:

```
Hi, ${userName}!
```

Therefore, how to recognize

```
${userName}
```

if it's exist in message?

And my template:

```
<h1>
  <td id="message">
    ${message}
  </td>
</h1>
```

Comment: I want to pass a `${userName}` variable into the `${message}` variable

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it well, you are saying that `message` itself is a small template. In that case, you could use `<@message?interpret />`, where `?interpret` will parse `message` as template content, and then `<@.../>` will invoke it.